# Javascript module pattern with undefined specified

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, undefined

I believe jQuery uses undefined in the module pattern to avoid it being redefined to an unexpected value. I thought about doing this but whenever I compare undefined I tend (always?) to use

```
typeof foo === 'undefined'
```

So is there any point doing this:

```
(function (win, doc, RG, undefined)
{
  // App goes here

})(window, document, typeof RGraph === 'object' ? RGraph : {});
```

Comment: Not sure. Why not `(window, document, RGraph, undefined)`?

Comment: Because then you'd be passing in the global value of undefined - which could be 2 if some, ummm, clever dick had reassigned it.

Comment: If you have a reliable _undefined_ to compare to as per the method you show then you don't need to use _typeof_ (unless you want to check a variable that might not have been declared), so that makes your code a bit simpler. If you plan to use _typeof_ in all cases regardless then no, there's no point declaring _undefined_ like that. Another way to reliably get the value _undefined_ for comparison is to use _void 0_ - as in _if(foo===void 0)_.

Comment: @Richard Chrome console won't let me override `undefined`.

Comment: @nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn I just realised now that you've said that - it kinda makes my question moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whenever I compare undefined I tend (always?) to use `typeof foo === 'undefined'`

Well if you don't use `undefined` in your module then there is no point in declaring it as a parameter to ensure its value.

However, there's a question mark after your "always", and you can hardly know who else might work with your code in the future, so it still might be advisable.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to test whether a value is `undefined`:

**Method 1:** Use `typeof`:

```
if (typeof value === "undefined") {
    // do something
}
```

**Method 2:** Compare it with the variable `undefined`:

```
if (value === undefined) {
    // do something
}
```

**Method 3:** Compare it with `void 0`:

```
if (value === void 0) {
    // do something
}
```

**Q:** Which one should you use?

**A:** There are many factors to consider:

1. In terms of understandability `typeof` and `undefined` are the best.
2. In terms of minimum characters `undefined` is the best when minified.
3. In terms of performance (http://jsperf.com/type-of-undefined-vs-undefined):

   1. Both `undefined` and `void` are at par in most browsers (notably Firefox and Chrome).
   2. In Chrome `typeof` is slower than the other two but in Firefox it is the fastest.
4. Using `typeof` is the only way to test whether or not a variable exists.

Based on these factors I would say that `undefined` (method 2) is the best method. There's always the problem of `undefined` being overwritten. However if you're using the module pattern (which you should be doing in the browser) then you can get `undefined` for free:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    // you can use `undefined` safely here
}(jQuery));
```

Hence if you're using the module pattern then I would suggest you use the second method. It is readable, understandable and concise. The only disadvantage is that you won't be able to test whether or not a variable exists. However you can always fall back to `typeof` for that.